# Checking gitolite config before push

Tags: gitolite

I've just started using gitolite and I can't find a way to verify changes I've made to gitolite-admin repo, i.e. changes to configuration, before pushing. So what happens is that I make changes, commit and push only to learn that I've made a typo in the config file or a key file is missing. Nothing dramatic, but I end up with an ugly commit history, making it difficult to follow what was changed when. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either:

- amend your last commit locally and force a push to the remote gitolite-admin repo
  (`git commit --amend`, followed by a `git push --force`).
- or have an intermediate staging gitolite server in which you wan review/approve the changes before pushing the the live gitolite server.

Honestly, for gitolite I have always used the first option.

Comment: Thanks, force pushing is a legit solution here.